# Get number via RegularExpression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have many inputs fields with this way of syntax

```
<input name="AF[c_condition][1][0]" />
<input name="AF[c_condition][1][1]" />
<input name="AF[c_condition][1][2]" />

<input name="AF[c_user][1]" />
```

how to get by RegularExpression the number in first brackets only?

Comment: People will be more willing to help if you show what you've tried.

Comment: Do you really need regexp to do this? `"AF[whatever][1]".split("]")[1].slice(1)` works just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input string is `myinput`, then you can use javascript's `.match()` like this:

```
myinput.match(/<input name="AF\[c_\w+\]\[(\d+)\]/)
```

and then number would be stored in the first capture group, `$1`.

The `[` is preceded by  `\` because `[` is a special character in regex.

The special `\w` means "any word character".  The special `+` means "one or more times".  The special `\d` means "any digit".  The parenthesis around it capture it into the first capture group.

As you can see, my match pattern only matches the beginning part of your HTML tags.  You may choose to make your matches more robust than this example.

Comment: your example worked for me , But I want to replace the number in first bracket. How to do that ??

Comment: I solved like this
                    var pattren = /AF\[c_\w+\]\[(\d+)\]/;
                    var string = $(this).attr('name');

                    $(this).attr('name', string.replace(pattren,  function(original , group){
                        return original.replace(group,ReplaceWith);
                    }));

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

Use capturing groups to fetch what's between the first two brackets.

I think `match[1]` will get you the first capturing group. I'm not really proficient with JavaScript:

```
var mystring = "STRINGABOVE";
var myRegexp = /name="\w+\[\w+\]\[(\d+)\]/gm;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/jH4iW5/1